# Can this code (for loops) be simplified to look for duplicates, given the multiple conditions?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have snipped some of the code out here to just show the relevant bit:

```
void CImportOCLMAssignmentHistoryDlg::SetButtonStates()
{
    {
        // Don't allow import into the same assignment more than once.
        CByteArray aryImport;
        aryImport.SetSize(15);
        aryImport[0] = m_iImportOCLMHost;
        aryImport[1] = m_iImportOCLMCohost;
        aryImport[2] = m_iImportOCLMChairman;
        aryImport[3] = m_iImportOCLMOpenPrayer;
        aryImport[4] = m_iImportOCLMClosePrayer;
        aryImport[5] = m_iImportOCLMConductorCBS;
        aryImport[6] = m_iImportOCLMReaderCBS;
        aryImport[7] = m_iImportPTHost;
        aryImport[8] = m_iImportPTCohost;
        aryImport[9] = m_iImportPTChairman;
        aryImport[10] = m_iImportPTHospitality;
        aryImport[11] = m_iImportWTConductor;
        aryImport[12] = m_iImportWTReader;
        aryImport[13] = m_iImportPTSpeaker; // AJT v17.0.8
        aryImport[14] = m_iImportPTTheme;   // AJT v17.0.8

        COptionsDlg dlgOptions;
        REPORT_MODE_E eMode = dlgOptions.GetReportMode();
        bool bDuplicateAssignment = false;

        if (eMode == MODE_MEETING)
        {
            // The index values can't be duplicated within each meeting
            // Midweek 0 to 6
            // Weekend 7 to 14

            // Midweek
            for (int iAssignment = 0; iAssignment < 7; iAssignment++)
            {
                if (aryImport[iAssignment] != (BYTE)-1)
                {
                    for (int iAssignment2 = iAssignment + 1; iAssignment2 < 7; iAssignment2++)
                    {
                        if (aryImport[iAssignment2] == aryImport[iAssignment])
                        {
                            bDuplicateAssignment = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (bDuplicateAssignment)
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (!bDuplicateAssignment)
            {
                // Weekend
                for (int iAssignment = 7; iAssignment < aryImport.GetSize(); iAssignment++)
                {
                    if (aryImport[iAssignment] != (BYTE)-1)
                    {
                        for (int iAssignment2 = iAssignment + 1; iAssignment2 < aryImport.GetSize(); iAssignment2++)
                        {
                            if (aryImport[iAssignment2] == aryImport[iAssignment])
                            {
                                bDuplicateAssignment = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if (bDuplicateAssignment)
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The index values can't be duplicated anywhere in the array
            for (int iAssignment = 0; iAssignment < aryImport.GetSize(); iAssignment++)
            {
                if (aryImport[iAssignment] != (BYTE)-1)
                {
                    for (int iAssignment2 = iAssignment + 1; iAssignment2 < aryImport.GetSize(); iAssignment2++)
                    {
                        if (aryImport[iAssignment2] == aryImport[iAssignment])
                        {
                            bDuplicateAssignment = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (bDuplicateAssignment)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (bDuplicateAssignment)
            m_btnImport.EnableWindow(FALSE);
        else
            m_btnImport.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    }
}
```

The code is functional. I just wondered if it could be simplified without over-complicating readability.
No need to comment on my use of literal integers instead of `#define` or `enum` values. I am aware of that improvement. It is primarily the way I go about looking for duplicates. Can it be simplified?

Comment: Possibly more of a question for Code Review? However, a quick look through the first of each of your `for` loops suggests only one difference: a change between `7` and `aryImport.GetSize()`; so, assigning one of these values to a 'new' variable would make the loops identical ... or did I miss something?

Comment: ... and the extra stuff in the `else` block could just be moved to an `if (eMode != MODE_MEETING)` block, instead.

Comment: @AdrianMole I realise I could write a second function that is passed the byte array and a start / end range for comparing. I just wondered if somethign could be done within the function itself.

Comment: Sure: Have an `int limit = 7;` and then `if (eMode == MODE_MEETING) limit = aryImport.GetSize();` and use `limit` in the `for` loops (which are otherwise identical).

Comment: @AdrianMole Forgive me, my code was the wrong way round. When in meeting mode I must check both of the ranges for duplicates within each range.

Comment: @AdrianMole If you see corrected code, when the mode is Meeting, it just check BOTH ranges (0-6,7-14) as two ranges. An index can be use in both ranges.

Comment: @AdrianMole I have added my solution as an answer ...

Comment: A `for` loop in C++ code is a strong indication that you forgot to `#include <algorithm>`. Searching for duplicates can be replaced with [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) followed by [adjacent_find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find). If your container is already sorted, you can skip the first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of two nested passes through your array, you can use a bitmap to check for duplicates:

```
bool CImportOCLMAssignmentHistoryDlg::DetectDuplicateAssignment(CByteArray &aryImport, INT_PTR iMin, INT_PTR iMax)
{
  std::vector<bool> found(256);
  for (INT_PTR iAssignment = iMin; iAssignment < iMax; iAssignment++)
  {
    auto value = aryImport[iAssignment];
    if (value != (BYTE)-1)
    {
      if (found[value])
        return true;
      found[value] = true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

To make it more C++'y, use `std::vector<bool> found(256);` instead of C-style array; also saves some space.

Comment: [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) may or may not be space optimized. And it's likely the C++ container (if you want to call it that) with the most surprising behavior. A better choice here would be [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Answer (score 0):

I have done it like this for now:

```
void CImportOCLMAssignmentHistoryDlg::SetButtonStates()
{
    {
        // Don't allow import into the same assignment more than once.
        CByteArray aryImport;
        aryImport.SetSize(15);
        aryImport[0] = m_iImportOCLMHost;
        aryImport[1] = m_iImportOCLMCohost;
        aryImport[2] = m_iImportOCLMChairman;
        aryImport[3] = m_iImportOCLMOpenPrayer;
        aryImport[4] = m_iImportOCLMClosePrayer;
        aryImport[5] = m_iImportOCLMConductorCBS;
        aryImport[6] = m_iImportOCLMReaderCBS;
        aryImport[7] = m_iImportPTHost;
        aryImport[8] = m_iImportPTCohost;
        aryImport[9] = m_iImportPTChairman;
        aryImport[10] = m_iImportPTHospitality;
        aryImport[11] = m_iImportWTConductor;
        aryImport[12] = m_iImportWTReader;
        aryImport[13] = m_iImportPTSpeaker; // AJT v17.0.8
        aryImport[14] = m_iImportPTTheme;   // AJT v17.0.8

        COptionsDlg dlgOptions;
        REPORT_MODE_E eMode = dlgOptions.GetReportMode();
        bool bDuplicateAssignment = false;

        if (eMode == MODE_MEETING)
        {
            // The index values can't be duplicated within each meeting
            // Midweek 0 to 6
            // Weekend 7 to 14

            // Midweek
            bDuplicateAssignment = DetectDuplicateAssignment(aryImport, 0, 7);

            if (!bDuplicateAssignment)
            {
                // Weekend
                bDuplicateAssignment = DetectDuplicateAssignment(aryImport, 7, aryImport.GetSize());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // The index values can't be duplicated anywhere in the array
            bDuplicateAssignment = DetectDuplicateAssignment(aryImport, 0, aryImport.GetSize());
        }

        if (bDuplicateAssignment)
            m_btnImport.EnableWindow(FALSE);
        else
            m_btnImport.EnableWindow(TRUE);
    }
}

bool CImportOCLMAssignmentHistoryDlg::DetectDuplicateAssignment(CByteArray &aryImport, INT_PTR iMin, INT_PTR iMax)
{
    bool bDuplicateAssignment = false;

    for (INT_PTR iAssignment = iMin; iAssignment < iMax; iAssignment++)
    {
        if (aryImport[iAssignment] != (BYTE)-1)
        {
            for (INT_PTR iAssignment2 = iAssignment + 1; iAssignment2 < iMax; iAssignment2++)
            {
                if (aryImport[iAssignment2] == aryImport[iAssignment])
                {
                    bDuplicateAssignment = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (bDuplicateAssignment)
                break;
        }
    }

    return bDuplicateAssignment;
}
```

If anyone has an alternative approach please let me know. Thanks.